# Where should the forms.py file be located?

Tags: python, django, forms, project-structure, project-structuring

I'm starting to write my first Django project right now and I need to make my `forms.py` file for an app. I've seen some tutorials store the file under the main folder for the project and some in the app directory.

1. Which layout is the best for me if I want to make a form that only applies to one app?
2. Is it suitable to make more than one file to keep my forms code in?

Thanks!

Comment: I would put it in the same folder as the app itself. If you have multiple apps with different forms files, I would just keep them in their respective app folder.

Comment: Okay thanks. So it really isn't important where I put it?

Comment: I would keep the form file for each app in the same folder of that app. So a form file for `app_a` would be in the `app_a` directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the standard layout:

```
├── apps/
|    ├── [app]/
|    |     ├── __init__.py
|    |     ├── urls.py
|    |     ├── models.py
|    |     ├── forms.py # Forms
|    |     ├── admin.py
|    |     ├── views.py
|    |     ├── migrations/
|    |     ├── management/
|    |     ├── templates/ # Here or in the project root
|    |     └── (other)
|    |
|    └── __init__.py
|
...
```

In short: keep all forms relevant to the app *in the app*. It's conceptually consistent, intuitive and makes code more maintainable (by separation).

Multi-app forms/components are rather rare. You can keep them in app named "*common*". This is a very popular convention.

This way you can import `forms` into `views` without a hassle:

```
from .forms import FormA, FormB
# or 
from . import forms
# or
from .forms import *
# and from common:
from ..common import forms as common_forms
```

Regarding your second question: absolutely - if benefits of the separation (such clean project layout, maintainability, more verbose filenames) are worth the trouble (e.g. of importing multiple files instead of one). There are no hard rules, so you must calculate the trade-offs and decide.

Comment: Thanks for all this!